# Расскажите про Python

Tags: python

Хотел бы узнать немного про Python, препод очень рекомендовал. Что за язык, какие особенности, да и вообще мнение тех кто уже пишет или писал на нём. Также неплохо бы и хорошие ссылки.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Язык очень хорош тем, что позволяет быстро писать рабочие программы. Иногда целые листинги программ таких языков как Java, C++, C# можно заменить всего одной аналогичной строкой на питоне. Помню писал давно программку решения судоку: функция принимающая массив исходных данных и возвращающая ответ состояла из 30-40 строк кода.  Язык очень **краток** и **красив**. Это основное за что я его люблю.
**Высокая читаемость кода**, его организация иерархии при помощи отступов изначально учит оформлять код.
**Портируемость** на очень высоком уровне. Питон существует наверно для всех платформ.
Большое количество модулей позволит **не изобретать велосипед**.
**Обьектно-ориентированность**. Все в питоне является объектами.
[python.org](http://python.org)
Стоит набрать в поиске учебник питон, и Вы тут же увидите кучу хороших учебников.
UPD 
**Простота**. Его конструкции очень просты и понятны. Как пример приведу срезы массивов arr[5:10] (срез от 5 до 10 элемента), arr[5:] (от пятого элемента до конца), arr[:-5] (от начала до 5 элемента с конца). И впомните как добиться аналогичного эффекта в других языках.

Comment: А в какой среде лучше писать?

Comment: а мне ещё нравится итроспекция...

Comment: IDLE как стандартное средство неплох.  
Еще неплохо писать в AkelPad с подсветкой синтаксиса и сворачиванием кода.

Comment: @ReinRaus все таки AkelPad - это текстовый редактор, а не IDE

Comment: Ну вообще да, но Python IDE не сильно и нужен

Comment: @Святослав, если вы хотите заниматься именно разработкой, лучше все-таки привыкнуть к какой-нибудь IDE, например, PyCharm by JetBrains (есть CommunityEdition).
Можно, конечно, всё писать в текстовом редакторе с подсветкой, но все же для больших проектов, в реалиях ограниченного времени, специальная среда сильно удобнее. Хотя, тот же vim можно очень сильно приблизить к полноценной IDE (но на это, в свою очередь, придется предварительно потратить немало усилий, если делать это впервые).

Answer (score 1):

Python наверно лучший язык, и его можно поставить с такими раскрученными как C/C#/C++ на ровне, просто он не сильно популярен. Раз - можно писать под веб, и много других фич которые я не смогу описать в этом после. В заключение: **стоит попробовать**.

Comment: Просто до этого я писал на C#, вот не знаю переходить или нет...

Comment: я тоже пишу на С#, но сначала у меня был питон, вещь занятная и препод зря рекомендовать не будет.

Comment: Ну что ж попробую.

Comment: @Святослав тогда вам нужен не простой питон, а железный. http://ironpython.codeplex.com/

Comment: Питон язык очень хороший, но у него есть одна проблема (во всяком случае, у нативного интерпертируемого питона) - скорость выполнения программ, которая довольна низка. Если это непринципиально, то все в порядке. Но где нужна скорость, надо смотреть в сторону других языков или в сторону связки с такими языками, как Си или С++.

Comment: @mikillskegg В конце 90х была хохма (не знаю, справедливо ли это сейчас) -- питон обгонял джаву на вычислениях. За счёт numpy (или numeric, или как тогда пакет назывался). В остальных случаях отставал. (Что java -- не native код, оставим за скобками)

Comment: @mikillskegg, на самом деле питон не настолько медленный как о нем рассказывают :) Раньше он  действительно показывал низкую скорость при работе со строками, но сейчас вроде уже получше.  
Я бы прежде всего ориентировал питон для повседневных задач: автоматизация рутины, быстрое решение прикладных задач.  
А уж если Вам потребовались сложные и долгие вычисления, то **ни один** интерпретируемый язык Вам не поможет. Тут нужны низкоуровневые языки вроде C++, Assembler :)

Comment: P.S. Исключительно интуитивно (без реальных тестов), мне кажется, что Python работает с большими числами 1L несколько быстрее, чем Java с BigInteger. Хотя Java считается более шустрым языком, чем Python.

Comment: @ReinRaus, вот я о том же.

Comment: @ReinRaus Ассемблер для вычислений? Вы бредите, вероятно температура. Да и с C++ тут лучше не путаться. Язык для вычислений -- фортран. Доказано десятилетиями. А насчёт задач... Если раньше питоновцы хвастались MS Merchant server'ом, то сейчас столько весьма солидных приложений и инструментов...

Comment: @alexlz я там смайлик **:)** поставил сразу после Assembler, читайте внимательнее :)

Comment: @alexlz, современные математические библиотеки для С и С++ обеспечивают скорость расчетов не меньшую, чем фортран. Единственное его преимущество, это то, что при той же эффективности математическая часть программируется проще.

Comment: 1. Ну некоторые из этих библиотек уже активно иcпользуются на питоне (самый яркий пример -- sage). 2. На фортране уже написано и отлажено много кода. 3. Специалисты по вычислительной математике и матфизике к нему привыкли. Ну и в качестве добавочного аргумента за питон -- язык используется в качестве скриптового во многих интересных приложениях. Навскидку: gimp (совместно с другими), inkscape, scribus, blender и т.д.

Comment: @alexlz, Вы забыли про OpenOfficce :) Вот там без него точно никак (хотя он поддерживает и другие скриптовые языки: питон лучше)